# How to extend the duration of a Oauth 2 StoredCredential

Tags: java, google-api, google-oauth

I'm making a API for taking the content of a google sheet but every hour, the token "StoredCredential" expire so I must log back with the UI (the menu where you choose your google account), how can I extend the lifespan of the token since the program will be launch everyday and I don't want to input my google account every days?
I already tried to change the expiration time but that didn't work

Here my actual code :

```java
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    
    private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "u:\\tokens";

    private static final List<String> SCOPES =
            Arrays.asList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS,SheetsScopes.DRIVE);

    private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "credentials.json";

    private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws Exception {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        if (in == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        }
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
        
          FileDataStoreFactory fileDataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(new File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH));
              DataStore<StoredCredential> datastore = fileDataStoreFactory.getDataStore("StoredCredential");
              datastore.values().forEach(x -> x.setExpirationTimeMilliseconds((long) 999999999));
              //DEBUG
              datastore.values().forEach(x -> System.out.println(x.getExpirationTimeMilliseconds()));
              
        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                //.setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                .setCredentialDataStore(datastore)
                .setAccessType("online")
                .setApprovalPrompt(null)
                .build();
        LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
        
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
    }
```

Comment: IF its only this one sheet you will be accessing and you the developer control that sheet then you should consider using a service account.

Comment: How I can adapt the getCredentials to use a service account, I can't download any client_service.json for a service account (I'm sorry if this question is dumb, I never used Oauth 2 before and I'm a bit lost)

Comment: I just found how it work with a service account, Thanks for your advice, I spent 5 days trying to solve this problem ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the documentation for my other question, i found a way to extend the lifespan of the StoredCredential file, you need to change the Access Type from online to offline.

Corrected version :

```java
 private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    
    private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "u:\\tokens";

    private static final List<String> SCOPES =
            Arrays.asList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS,SheetsScopes.DRIVE);

    private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "credentials.json";

    private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws Exception {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        if (in == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        }
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
        
          FileDataStoreFactory fileDataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(new File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH));
              DataStore<StoredCredential> datastore = fileDataStoreFactory.getDataStore("StoredCredential");
              datastore.values().forEach(x -> x.setExpirationTimeMilliseconds((long) 999999999));
              //DEBUG
              datastore.values().forEach(x -> System.out.println(x.getExpirationTimeMilliseconds()));
              
        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                //.setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                .setCredentialDataStore(datastore)
                /* Here, we change the accessType */
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .setApprovalPrompt(null)
                .build();
        LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
```